# Set variable with REST API data

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I've never used a REST api and I'm having trouble figuring out how to set a variable with the returned `result.data`. I'm using Meteor with ReactJs and  console.log('countries', countries) is returning `undefined` while `console.log(result.data)` is returning the countries data.

```
export default class CountryPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const countries = HTTP.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all', (err, result) => {
      console.log(result.data);
      return result.data;
    });
    console.log('countries', countries);
    return (
      <div>  
        <Input type="select" name="countrySelect" id="countrySelect">
          {countries.map(country => (
            <option>{country.name}</option>
          ))}
        </Input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: (Note: unverified) as far as I can tell, the answer provided by Wesgur is correct in that you're not handling AJAX correctly. However, it should be noted that `render` is likely not the appropriate place for such a call. Place the AJAX call in `componentDidMount` and set state with the result

Comment: Isn't componentDidMount deprecated? @vapurrmaid

Comment: I thought that was `componentWillMount`, but I haven't used React in a while. [The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) seems to indicate this as well: `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`, while showing `componentDidMount` normally - so I assume it's safe to use still

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we use lifecycle method `componentDidMount` this is the best place to make API calls and set up subscriptions

```
 export default class CountryPage extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            countries: []
        }
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        HTTP.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all', (err, result) => {
          this.setState({countries:result.data})
        });
      }
      render() {
        const {countries} = this.state;
        return (
          <div>  
            <Input type="select" name="countrySelect" id="countrySelect">
              {countries.map(country => (
                <option>{country.name}</option>
              ))}
            </Input>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't componentDidMount deprecated? I read the docs and it said not to use this.

Comment: @Paul, initialize state

Comment: @bp123 `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` is deprecated.

Comment: @bp123 see my comment posted on the question - I think you've confused `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`

Comment: Thanks. You're right regarding componentDidMount. I think I'm mixing it up.

Comment: @bp123 No problem, ReactJS is changing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP request is an asynchronous task. You have to wait for the API's response so

```
export default class CountryPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    HTTP.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all', (err, result) => {
        const countries = result.data;
        console.log('countries', countries);
        return (
          <div>  
            <Input type="select" name="countrySelect" id="countrySelect">
              {countries.map(country => (
                <option>{country.name}</option>
              ))}
            </Input>
          </div>
        );
    });
  }
}
```