# Invalid Hook Call-My first React Function

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, return-value

Probably a newbie error or mis-use, but here we go.

Error on:  const [color, setColor] = useState([])

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:.

### What am I missing?

Component code:
...

```
        this.state = {
            nbrrecs:'',
            pageOfItems: [],
            pageSize: 5,
            fcolor:''
        };

        this.setState({fcolor:GetColor(127,90)});
render(){
return(
                 <h2 className="text-center">{this.fcolor}</h2>
           <td style={{color: GetColor(127,90)}} >{GetColor(127,90)} </td>
```

### ...

GetColor.js
...

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SiteReportCardMasterService from '../Services/SiteReportCardMasterService';

    const GetColor = (id,rptvalue) =>
    {
        const [color, setColor] = useState([])
        useEffect(() =>{
        SiteReportCardMasterService.getSiteReportCardMasterById(id).then( (res) =>{
            if (rptvalue === 0) setColor(res.data.sitereportcardmasterColore)
            if (rptvalue < 70) setColor(res.data.sitereportcardmasterColord)
            if (rptvalue >= 70 && rptvalue <80) setColor(res.data.sitereportcardmasterColorc)
            if (rptvalue >= 80 && rptvalue <90) setColor(res.data.sitereportcardmasterColorb)
            if (rptvalue >= 90) setColor(res.data.sitereportcardmasterColora)
            })
        })
        return color
    };
    export default GetColor;
```

...

Comment: The only thing wrong now would be the name `GetColor` is not valid for a custom hook (a function that uses other hooks inside). It should be called `useGetColor`. (This causes the 2nd error message). Otherwise everything looks in working order.

Comment: You will also help yourself and your colleagues a lot by applying good code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

`GetColor` doesn't return anything.

You do call `return`, but it is inside an inner arrow function (`(res) =>{...return}`), and that return only applies to that function.

Also, your variable `color` is defined inside the scope of the inner function so isn't accessible outside.

It would be hard to say exactly what you need without knowing what this does `SiteReportCardMasterService.getSiteReportCardMasterById(id)`, but it seems that it is an async function. If you want to use its result in a variable you would have to deal with this and wait for the result properly, and you could set a property in your component with a callback function that gets passed into `GetColor`

Comment: Yes..you are on the right track. SiteReportCardMasterService.getSiteReportCardMasterById(id) is a I/O call to AXIOS to the MySQL Springboot REST API backend. I need to get the RES data and then do the logic and then pass the color value back and receive it into the Component. I know what I want, just not how to make it happen in the code (with consideration for the issues you recognize). What can I do to help you , help me? (Looking for trust worthy consultant to help finish a 95% completed project also). @Ben Gooding – 
HighwayRob

Comment: You should read up on how to set variables in components via api calls (anything async actually). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068144/set-variable-with-rest-api-data

Comment: You can achieve this in your setup by passing a callback function that is defined in your component into `GetColor` which you should call inside your `.then`.

Comment: Modified function to look more Function like (above). Now I get the Invalid Hook Call error.  DO I also have to make this a asynch function with an await?
I know if I  can code one function to work, I will be off and running and be able to clean up some repetitive code other places in my system. @Ben Gooding